# Unable to load the Starteam Dump into SVN

Tags: svn, starteam

I have a dump created from StarTeam 2008 R 2 (10.4.7.-64)
using [svn importer](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer.php) 1.1-M8.
However when I a try to import the dump I get this error:

```
* adding path : tags/Test/GH/13_Environment/Process/Capgemini EN Template - Business Case.doc ...
svnadmin: File already exists: filesystem 'help\db', transaction '2-2', 
path 'tags/Test/GH/13_Environment/Process/Capgemini EN Template - Business Case.doc'
```

I can see from the `svn admin` load o/p that the file has been added already.
Maybe the dump created by SVN Importer is not correct.

Can anyone offer any advice on solving this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with the StarTeam model used by SVN Importer.  Essentially what has happened is the tool is writing the dump file with multiple versions of the same file in the same revision. In my observation, this has turned out only to occur when there were multiple tags (ST labels) for the same SVN revision. I was able to resolve the issue by having the code check before it adds a ST file revision to a SVN revision to see if the same file has already been added to that SVN revision.  I have submitted the code to Polarion for them to review and my understanding at this point is that it will eventually be added in to the project.

Comment: Just now realized I responded to a two year old question ... oops

Comment: which makes it still a great answer!

Comment: Do you have a version of the modified SVN Importer that is publically available?  Inquiring minds want to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched through the export to see if it contains duplicates of that file?  I have seen times where StarTeam will essentially contain duplicates of a file if someone added it to a project and also shared the file from a different project.